# What aspect of meaning is not captured by the translation from natural language to PropL?

Tags: translation, formal-semantics

So I was given the sentence "I don’t drink and drive", and asked to translate it into PropL and indicate at least one aspect of meaning that the logical translation doesn’t
capture.
To translate it into PropL, I said
let P = I drive and let Q = I drink.
Then, "I don’t drink and drive" can be translated as ~(P^Q).
However, I am having trouble determining what aspect of meaning isn't captured. Is it that "I don’t drink and drive" can be taken to mean "I don't drink, nor do I drive"?
Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: "drink and drive" idiomatically means something different from the sum of its parts.

Comment: So would it be that the sentence can mean that I don't drink while driving, or I don't drink and then drive? Thank you for the guidance

Comment: I guess I am also a little confused then of what meaning ~(P^Q) does capture.

Comment: Not much. `And` is a basic functor, and all it says is TFFF. The simultaneity is not present, because there's no mention of time at all. P and Q both can represent any proposition at all, so there's no way in [Propositional Calculus](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) to take them apart (except with a special predicate like `Simultaneous`, but that just kicks the ball down the road).

Comment: What is PropL?   Is it a programming language, a constructed language, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

Somebody who neither drinks nor drives would say *I don't drink or drive*.

*I don't drink and drive* pragmatically means *I don't drive when I am or might be under the influence of alcohol*. The only possible way that that interpretation would be open to a system that only has a lexicon and rules of composition would be if *drink and drive* were an item in the lexicon, that took precedence over its components.

Notice also that *drink and drive* is far more often used in a negative polarity context than otherwise. The iWeb corpus has 2893 instances of "drink and drive", but only 4 of "will drink and drive" (and these are all general statements about "the likelihood that" or "the optimist will")